# mysql workbench duplicate key error

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a data set with a list of country names, and the country names are repeated once for "Males" and then again for "Females".

For example:

```
c_name     gender
China      M
Greece     M
Algeria    M
China      F
Greece     F
Algeria    F
```

When I create table and import data from a csv file, I get a 'duplicate key' error. I am wondering if this has anything to do with the engine settings? Any ideas how this can be resolved? (I know it works because my friend got it to work on her Mac, and she did not have the option to choose 'Collate' or 'Engine' when creating her tables, but I'm on Windows)

EDIT: Here's how I'm creating the table:

CREATE TABLE `dbs`.`enrollment` (

`e_id` INT NOT NULL,

`c_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,

`gender` VARCHAR(45) NULL,

`2001` INT NULL,

`2002` INT NULL,

`2003` INT NULL,

`2004` INT NULL,

`2005` INT NULL,

`2006` INT NULL,

`2007` INT NULL,

`2008` INT NULL,

`2009` INT NULL,

`2010` INT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (`e_id`, `c_name`));

Comment: Can you include the table definition? What indexes do you have on the table?

Comment: updated! also I haven't made any additions to the index, it just says "PRIMARY" "PRIMARY"

Comment: Somewhere in your data, you have the e_id, c_name pair having the same values in more than one row.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend might set a primary key with c_name in this table ,if you want to have a change ,you can cancel the primary key。

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to answer if you shared the query which is used for the above. I agree with Walker Li.

If your query is something like this..

```
CREATE TABLE enrollment (
  c_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  gender VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (c_name)
);
```

You can change it by removing the primary id line as

```
CREATE TABLE enrollment (
  c_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  gender VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Hope this solves your problem.

If your csv data contains any unique column as ID you could use it as primary key as,

```
CREATE TABLE enrollment (
  e_id INT NOT NULL,
  gender VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (e_id)
);
```

A table can have only one primary key. Remove c_name in the last line and only have e_id as shown below

```
PRIMARY KEY (e_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The combination of e_id and c_name must be unique. If not you can create an additional artifical primary key as work around.

```
CREATE TABLE `enrollment` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `e_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `c_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `2001` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `2002` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `2003` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `2004` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `2005` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `2006` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `2007` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `2008` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `2009` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `2010` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```